# Windows 8.1 switches off after some time in suspend

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, hibernate

I am running a windows 8.1 on my laptop. I configured the Power button as suspend to RAM. Additionally I have Hibernate (Suspend to HDD), fastboot is deactivated.

When I put the OS into Suspend to RAM, sometimes after some time it switches off completely. Not Hibernate but OFF. There is enough battery left and the battery itself is good.

Why does it switch off? Is there some timer somewhere left? I think it is something about 1 day in suspend.

Comment: Hibernate does switch the power off to the device, and will outwardly not show any signs of running. How do you know it's being shutdown rather than hibernating?

Comment: I suspended the OS with a Virtual machine running. After 1 day of suspend to RAM the Host OS booted from OFF, the VM was gone. If I use Hibernate the VM is still there, the Problem is when the laptop is in Suspend to RAM for some time. (Battery is not empty)

Comment: Have a check through all the power settings within control panel, it's possible you've got something that is shutting the machine down.